# Running docker-Desktop on Windows 10 cannot restart containers after system restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running Docker-Dektop Version 2.1.0.0 (36874) on a Windows 10 environment.
I am using two separate container compositions, one of these binding to port 8081 on my machine, and the other binding to 9990 and 8787.

After a system restart, I am unable to start these container compositions again, because the ports are already bound.

So far, I have tried multiple approaches to solve this:

- manually stop all containers prior to system shutdown
- manually stop and remove all containers prior to system shutdown
- the above, plus explicitly stopping the docker application prior to system shutdown
- removing all containers after system startup and prior to restart
- pruning the networks after container removal
- restart docker app prior to restarting containers (this worked up until the last update)

I did fiddle around with the compose files and the configuration, but taht would be too much detail to go into right now; all of these did not help.

What I recently found was, directly after a system startup and prior to starting any container, that the process `com.docker.backend` was already listening to the bound ports. This is confusing as the containers were shut down prior to system shutdown and are not run with a restart-command.

So I explicitly quit the docker desktop app, and the process still remaind, and it still bound the ports.

After manually killing the process as administrator from the power shell, and restarting the docker desktop application, my containers were able to start again.

Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone know a "fix" for this at all?

And, of course, is this even the right page to ask? As this is not strictly programming, I am unsure.

Comment: check listening ports using `netstat -a -b -n` and stop the service that using your Container ports

Comment: I do - the service is `com.docker.backend`. Notably, that is the **only** service listening to these ports. Stopping that process requires to then restart the docker-desktop application to run containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away after the update to version 2.1.0.1 (37199)

Comment: How can we solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Docker setup gets screwed up sometimes, so try deleting `%appdata%\Docker`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30055348)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I updated answer with bit more explanation, hope that helps.